# Unable to run the android app without setting "window no title" to "true"

Tags: android, styles, statusbar

Something is making my app crash. I am not sure why I need to run a drawing app

my styles.xml file:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

this is my styles.xml v21 file

```
<resources>
        <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
            **<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>**
            <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
            <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        </style>

</resources>
```

If I set the above to false, my drawing app will crash.

My drawingcontent.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/drawing_main"
        tools:context=".DrawingActivity">


            android:id="@+id/custom_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar_bottom" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The other is my drawing_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".DrawingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.example.kahheng.smartchat.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar_bottom" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me what wrong with my code and why I must remove the statusbar?
anyone got a idea?

I got code from here
http://www.valokafor.com/android-drawing-app-tutorial-pt-2/

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Toolbar in your XML, and I presume you are using that Toolbar as your ActionBar. Therefore, you can't have another action bar from the theme (there can be only 1 action bar in one activity). So to use the Toolbar as action bar, you have to either use "window no title" or inherit from one of the .NoActionBar themes.

Comment: but when I set to NoActionbar, the entire app became with actionbar. How can I get back the actionbar

Comment: You have to use the toolbar as actionbar.
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);